# Socket programming stuck waiting for a response from the server

Tags: python, sockets

For a class assignment I need to use the socket API to build a file transfer application. For this project there two connections with the client and server, one is called the control and is used to send error messages and the other is used to send data. My question is, on the client side how can I keep the control socket open and waiting for any possible error messages to be received from the server while not blocking the rest of the program from running?

Example code (removed some elements)

```
  #Create the socket to bind to the server
  clientSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
  clientSocket.connect((serverName,portNum))
 clientSocket.send(sendCommand)  # Send to the server in the control connection contains either the list or get command

  (If command is valid server makes a data connection and waits for client to connect)
  clientData = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
  clientData.connect((serverName,dataport))  #Client connects

  recCommand = clientData.recv(2000)  #Receive the data from server if command is successful
  badCommand = clientSocket.recv(2000) #But if there is an error then I need to skip the clientData.recv and catch the error message in bad Command
```

Answer (score 0):

when there is an error, the data-socket should be closed by the server, so recv ends automatically.